# mac mini で、 JIS キーボードを利用する際に、 変換キーを ctrl に割り当てたい

Tags: macos, os-x-key-bindings, mac-mini

今、 mac mini で JIS キーボードを利用しているのですが、 emacs を利用するために、右手の親指で押せる場所に ctrl が欲しいです。

「変換」キーを ctrl に入れ替えたいのですが、これはどうやったら実現できるでしょうか。(どういう実現方法があるのかすら分かっていない状態です）

---

関連するかもしれない質問: [EmacsのキーバインドにMacの「英数」キーを使う方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/26897/754)

「英数」キーボード入力を emacs プロセスに送って、それを emacs で処理したい、が上の質問でやりたいこと。まず、この質問では emacs の利用を想定しているが、 emacs 自体には関係のない質問であるという認識です。また、上記質問ではおそらく mac book air であるとか、 apple 社が利用するキーボードを利用していると推測されますが、 mac mini で、 JIS キーボードだった時に、そもそも普通の(英字・アップル社の)キーボードにはない「変換」キーって変更できるのか・できないのかの判断が私にはできず、なので別の質問だと考えています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Karabiner Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html)をインストールし、キー入替えの設定を行うことで(JIS配列特有のものでも)任意のキー割り当てが可能です。
[image]

---

(以下は質問時の回答です。)

<s>キーバインドの定番変更アプリ、[Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.ja)はJISキーボード特有の設定もサポートしてたはずです。</s>

質問の用を足すのは[Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.ja)でしたね(?)

Comment: あ、すいません、もし、一瞬 upvote してそのあと消したことに対しての意図を聞いているのでしたら、「おお、使ってみよう。 +1」 -> 「いや、まてよ、これちゃんと自分のやりたいことできるのか？検証してから upvote しよう」 -> ひとまず upvote をとりやめる    です。 Karabiner 、 seil があるんですね。まず時間が取れたら使ってみます。

Comment: あ、いや回答で書くの間違えたので自問です。なお、リンク先にもあるようにSierraでは動かず、また後継アプリは統合されたそうです。

Comment: もしかしたら状況が変わっているかもしれないので、共有: High Sierra で今動いているのは Karabiner です。